# Can I provide Tor non-exit node while using same Tor as SOCKS proxy?

Tags: configuration

I'm using Tor for localhost SOCKS proxy and I want to provide Tor non-exit node using same torrc file.

```
ORPort 443
Exitpolicy reject *:*
Nickname ieditedtheconfig
ContactInfo human@...
AccountingStart day 0:00
AccountingMax 512 MBytes
RelayBandwidthRate 5120 KBytes
RelayBandwidthBurst 10240 KBytes
SocksPort 127.0.0.1:9050
```

If I read the manual correctly, above config will make Tor into hibernation state after it reached AccountingMax.

Question:
So that means I can't use localhost:9050 for SOCKS proxy at all?
Can I use my Tor Socks proxy while providing limited Tor node?

There is no online docs clearly explains it.

Comment: I think you will need to run two tor processes for this since bandwidth accounting will apply to both use cases (the relay and the client proxy).

Answer (score 0):

As you already guessed and Steve correctly pointed out, the restrictions apply to both relay and client.
You will have to run two instances to separate relay and client operation.

Regarding docs, it is clearly stated here
https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#Hibernation
and here
https://support.torproject.org/relay-operators/hibernation/

Answer (score 0):

The Accounting **is** strict - and that's how it has to be, but - it can't be used just alone, or you will expect not just the issue you already have. Tor's `torrc` has also a bandwidth options - add them **manually** and calculate the speeds according to your Accounting settings